# Add a new delegate for an Exchange account through python and EWS

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I'm working with exchangelib to get a list of delegates assigned to an exchange account and it is working properly. However what I'm trying to do now is to add a new delegate to the same exchange account, but I'm not sure if exchangelib provide this functionality.

I have tried to add it through the append and insert method of

```
config = Configuration(server=server, credentials=credentials, auth_type=NTLM)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=email, autodiscover=False, config=config, access_type=DELEGATE)
account.delegates.append("email@domain.com")
```

Does anyone know if it is possible with exchangelib or any other library for python?

Answer (score 0):

It has not been implemented in exchangelib yet. Only read access has been implemented, using the [GetDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getdelegate-operation) service. Write support would require implementing [AddDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/adddelegate-operation), [UpdateDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updatedelegate-operation), and [RemoveDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/removedelegate-operation).